# How to customize Devise New Session view content based on target URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I spent a lot of time researching this but can't seem to find a solution. I'm on Rails 4 and using Devise for authentication.

My problem: I'm using one single view for user sign-in (views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb). I'd like to customize the view's H1 text based on the target URL/path.

Ex: for all destination paths show "Account login". If target path is seller_onboarding_path, show "In order to onboard, please login first".

I have no idea how to capture the target path...

Any suggestions?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my own problem. Not sure that's the most elegant but it works.

On my view (sign in form), I check the value of ***session["user_return_to"]***. It contains the value of the target page. Based on the value, I pick the right title to display.

Answer (score 0):

You can store last page path with a before filter in the `RegistrationsController` of Devise. It would look something like this:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :store_history

  private
  def store_history
    @last_page = request.url
  end
end
```

After this you can just check what was the last page user visited with an `if.. else` statement  in`views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb` and display your `H1` tag text accordingly.